# Splunk UF not sending data to indexer

Tags: splunk

I have Splunk UF and Splunk Enterprise Server, both v8.2.1, running in docker containers but I am unable to see any data on the Enterprise Server with regards to the new index I created, 'mytest':

[image]

The Enterprise Server has default port 9997 active as a receiver port:

[image]

Both of the containers are connected to 'splunk' network I created:

```
        "Containers": {
        "0f9e44620ce9fba16df21af6d2253c4b02b9714cb3ea126a616f10d06f836eb9": {
            "Name": "dspinelli-uf",
            "EndpointID": "0e1dd065ee3d815c943a8b52e6107e53a4b57d9e3103b17d1461611543769869",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "3a1a084561eda8013baa8847f4ca30fd68eb74468ff666195bf1c15e0f8a280f": {
            "Name": "dspinelli-ent",
            "EndpointID": "7159b1a41840f9dfae04b50bb61386f8c3ac2233aee334026b9f1d685cfcf571",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
```

Inputs.conf on the UF:

```
[splunktcp://9997]
disabled = 0

[http://hec-uf]
description = UF HTTP Event Collector
disabled = 0
token = 4022d42f-9132-442a-8a79-5d3eea1ad40d
index = mytest
indexes = mytest
outputgroup = tcpout
```

Outputs.conf on UF:

```
[indexAndForward]
index = false

[tcpout]
defaultGroup = default-autolb-group

[tcpout:default-autolb-group]
server = dspinelli-ent:9997

[tcpout-server://dspinelli-ent:9997]
```

Communication between the UF and Enterprise Server is established:

```
netstat -an | grep 9997
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9997            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 172.18.0.3:44420        172.18.0.2:9997         ESTABLISHED

./bin/splunk list forward-server
Active forwards:
        dspinelli-ent:9997
Configured but inactive forwards:
        None
```

Attempt to curl the UF with some test data shows success:

```
curl -k https://x.x.x.x:8087/services/collector \
> -H 'Authorization: Splunk 4022d42f-9132-442a-8a79-5d3eea1ad40d' \
> -d '{"sourcetype": "demo", "event":"Hello, I was sent from UF"}'
{"text":"Success","code":0}
```

However, no data is ever displayed on the index in Enterprise Server:

[image]

Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong here or what the next steps would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with inputs.conf.  Updated as follows:

```
[http://hec-uf]
description = UF HTTP Event Collector
disabled = 0
token = 4022d42f-9132-442a-8a79-5d3eea1ad40d
_TCP_ROUTING = *
index = _internal
```

After update/restart the messages started to be received on Enterprise:

[image]